# Does this particular limit exist?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

$f(x)$ is a continuous, decreasing function from the positive reals to the positive reals.

Let $$a_N = \sum_{1}^Nf(n) - \int_{1}^N f(x)dx.$$

Does the limit of $a_N$ always exist? Prove it or give a counterexample.

I would like some hints only.

Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula

Comment: First hint: Split $\int_1^N =\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\int_n^{n+1}$.

Comment: Can I get a second hint, @PhoemueX?  I see now that the integrals from n to n+1 all have interval length = 1.  I tried expressing the integral (from n to n+1) as a limit of a  Riemann sum, but am not getting anywhere with this so far.  I'm also not sure whether swapping sums  and integrals -- or the sum and the limit (from the Riemann sum) would be valid or useful...

Comment: Thanks for your very cool first hint, btw.

Comment: @user248003: Christian Blatter already posted what I had in mind. Does his hint help you?

Comment: Hi, @PhoemueX, using Christian Blatter's hint, I can now bound $a_N$ from above (and below) with f(N) + f(1) - f(N) = f(1).  However, I can't seem to show monotonicity of $a_N$ to guarantee that its limit exists.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: I think I'm just not computing a_N+1 correctly ...

Answer (score 3):

Write $a_N$ in the form
$$a_N=f(N)+\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\left(f(k)-\int_k^{k+1} f(t)\>dt\right)\ .$$ Here the $\lim_{N\to\infty} f(N)$ exists since $f$ is monotonically decreasing with $0$ as lower bound. On the other hand $$c_k:=f(k)-\int_k^{k+1} f(t)\>dt$$ can be estimated by
$$0\leq c_k\leq f(k)-f(k+1)\ .$$
It follows that the partial sums $s_N:=\sum_{k=1}^{N-1} c_k$ are monotonically increasing and that
$$s_N\leq\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\bigl(f(k)-f(k+1)\bigr)=f(1)-f(N)\leq f(1)\qquad(N\geq1)\ .$$
Therefore the $\lim_{N\to\infty} s_N$ exists as well, and so does the limit of the $a_N=f(N)+s_N$.

Comment: Hi, @ChristianBlatter: if I use this estimate, and now I instead look at the sum of f(k) - f(k+1), sum over k, I get a telescoping sum, which results in f(1) - f(N).  Then this means that $a_N$ is bounded above by f(N) + f(1) - f(N) = f(1).  Where can I go from here?  This bound doesn't seem helpful, if I want to now go for the computation of a_N+1 ...

Comment: hmm... let's see what a_N+1 actually is ...

Comment: a_N+1 is also bounded above by f(1) ... which doesn't seem to help.  What do you think, @ChristianBlatter?  Thanks,

Comment: so I have that $a_N$ is bounded above by f(1) for all n.  What about a lower bound on $a_N$?  Also would like to show that $a_N$ is monotonic to guarantee the limit exists...

Comment: @LebronJames: Each summand is non-negative. Thus, the sequence of partial sums is nondecreasing (if you drop the first term, $f(N)$). But the first term, $f(N)$ is decreasing by assumption on $f$.

Comment: Hi @PhoemueX, I think you're leading me to say that since f(N) is decreasing, then this makes $a_N$ a decreasing positive sequence, hence bounded below by zero and must have a limit by the Monotone Convergence Theorem.  But I still can't say this with confidence.  How can I be sure that $a_N$ is decreasing?  I need to say something stronger than just observing that the sequence of partial sums is nondecreasing...  -- if it were increasing, then $a_N$ may not even be a decreasing sequence...

Comment: hmm...since the series' summands are positive / non-negative, we can compare the series with the series of f(k) - f(k+1), using Christian Blatter's hint.  But this bigger series converges, because of the telescoping sum and the fact that f is decreasing, hence the original series converges, by the Comparison Test.  So $a_N$ is a sum of f(N) + a convergent series.  Am I pretty close or have I gotten further away from the answer, @PhoemueX?

Comment: @LebronJames: No, that is exactly right. But since you assume that $f$ is decreasing and non-negative, the sequence $f(N)$ is also decreasing and bounded below, hence convergent.

Comment: Ok, got it.  Thanks very much for your help, @PhoemueX.

Comment: Thanks, as always, @ChristianBlatter, for your elegant solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Take $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$ then $\lim a_n$ won't exists.

Comment: on what condition(s) $lim \quad a_n$ exist?

Comment: For your $f$ both the sum and the integral converge when $N\to\infty$.